# Python: Updating one key of the pair adding the previous value to the new one - Dictionary/Hash

Tags: python, dictionary, hash, overriding, updating

> In this problem giving a sequence of pairs: «number of the student» «grade(partial)», it gives us the final grade of the students ordered from the highest grade to the lowest, and for the students with the same grade it orders them using the student number from lower to higher.

eg.
**input:**

```
10885 10
70000 6
70000 10
60000 4
70000 4
60000 4
10885 10
```

**output:**

```
10885 20
70000 20
60000 8
```

Here's the code I have so far:

```
nice={}

try:

    with open('grades.txt') as file:
        data = file.readlines()

except IOError as ioerr:
    print(str(ioerr))


for each_line in data:
    (number, grade) = each_line.split()
    nice[number]=grade 

for num,grade in sorted(nice.items()):
    print(num,grade)
```

output I get:

```
10885 10
60000 4
70000 4
```

Which means the grade is being overriden everytime it updates, Is there I way I can **sum** the **grade** *if it belongs* to that certain **student number** instead of overidding it?

something of the likes of:

```
for num,grade in sorted(nice.items()):
    if(num in finaldic): //finaldic being a new dicionary that we would create
        //find the number and update the grade adding it to the existent 
    else():
        //add new number and grade
```

Yet I believe the main problem of my code lies around here:

```
    for each_line in data:
        (number, grade) = each_line.split()
        nice[number]=grade
```

Comment: Can you show exactly what your desired output should look like?

Comment: Is the the output you want:`{'10885': [10, 10], '70000': [6, 10, 4], '60000': [4, 4]}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, when assigned to the dictionary, see if the value exists and if it does not, set it to 0. Then add to it:

```
for each_line in data:
  (number, grade) = each_line.split()
  if number not in nice:
      nice[number] = 0
  nice[number] += int(grade)
```

Comment: I think grade in this instance is going to be a string, so you'll probably want to cast it to a float or an int, but otherwise this is right.

Comment: I'm sorry to further bother you sir, but is there I way you could help me with displaying/sorting the output? -http://stackoverflow.com/a/31466723/5125477

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setdefault`:

```
nice={}
try:

    with open('grades.txt') as file:
        data = file.readlines()

except IOError as ioerr:
    print(str(ioerr))

for each_line in data:
    (number, grade) = each_line.split()
    nice.setdefault(number, []).append(int(grade))
print (nice)
```

This is the output:

```
{'10885': [10, 10], '70000': [6, 10, 4], '60000': [4, 4]}
```

If you want to go further and `sum` the `grade`, you can use `dictionary comprehension`, creating a new dictionary from `nice` like this:

```
nice_sum = {k:sum(v) for k,v in nice.items()}
print (nice_sum)
```

The output for `nice_sum`:

```
{'10885': 20, '70000': 20, '60000': 8}
```

Comment: Your code indeed gives another solution for the problem I was getting! Thank you for your time sir! I have a new problem now, sorting the display data to conform the requisites. Check my answer/question below if you have the time please sir!: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31466723/5125477

Comment: @LuisNetto Perhaps you should post a new question in a new post for this new problem as in this post you have your question in your original post and an accepted answer for that question already. This post will get too complicated if you pile up questions.

Comment: @LuisNetto In any case, what do you mean by "order two different students"?

Comment: if two students have the same final grade (eg, student1 with student number **"1000"** has a final grade of: **"19"** ; student2 with student number **"1001"** has a final grade of **"19"**; then student2 comes first (1001>1000) yet if student3 with student number **"999"** has a final grade of **"20"** : student3>student2>student1